# cisco 870 assign IP

Tags: cisco, ip, http, ios

I'll try to be "short." I've successfully enabled http server option on my Cisco 870, now I need to reach it and use the web based configuration. I haven't found how to assign an IP to the router itself. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign an IP address either to a physical (Ethernet) interface or to a VLAN including one or more of them; the default configuration has all interfaces sitting on VLAN 1, so the easiest approach is assigning an IP address to it.

That would be:

```
! Enters configuration mode
configure terminal

! Enters configuration of interface VLAN 1
interface vlan1

! Configures IP address and subnet mask
ip address <IP ADDRESS> <SUBNET MASK>

! Assure interface is not down
no shutdown

! Exits configuration of interface VLAN 1
end

! Exits configuration mode
exit
```

Example:

```
configure terminal
interface vlan1
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
end
exit
```

Comment: @Brenn: it's true that VLAN interfaces are down by default for newly-created VLANs, but not for the default one; anyway, issuing a "no shutdown" can't do any harm, so I'm leaving it there.